# history.pushState seems to cause gtag.js to load again (SPA)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, pushstate, gtag.js

My SPA was re-loading GTAG every time I changed pages. Every post online was saying I have to be causing GTAG to load again in my code. So, I put together a small rough sample to re-create the issue. What am I doing that is causing the multiple loads? I only notice it because the Google Tag Assistant extension in Chrome points it out "Multiple installations of Global site tag (gtag.js) detected". Everything seems to be getting tracked fine.

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_MEASUREMENT_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {'send_page_view': true});
</script>

<title>Single Page</title>
<script>
function change_page_function(page_nm)
{
    var page = {'page':page_nm};
    history.pushState(page, page_nm, '/'+page_nm);
    gtag('event', 'page_view', {'page_title' : page_nm, 'page_path' : "/"+page_nm});
    //gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {'page_path': page_nm});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a onclick="change_page_function('One');return false;" href="javascript:void(0);">Page 1</a>
    <a onclick="change_page_function('Two');return false;" href="javascript:void(0);">Page 2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

In my real SPA if I remove the history.pushState it does not load multiple gtag.js tags and it behaves and tracks fine. Minus the pretty urls of course. I also tried reverting back to Universal analytics and had the same issue. If I add GTM to this example it gets duplicated too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is Google Tag Assistant when used with Single Page Applications.
At least in my case. I would say make sure you aren't loading gtag.js or js twice by looking through the Network tab in the developer console.
https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/multiple-installations-of-google-tag-manager-detected/

Comment: This would be better if you explicitly explained why/how using Google Tag Assistant with a SPA was a problem. It's not clear from this answer what was causing you to load gtag.js more than once. Also note that if the problem isn't actually identifiable from the information that's in your question, then you should update your question to include enough information to be able to identify the actual problem. It might help to say in the question which SPA framework you're using, because it's not clear from the question that the `<head>` is being reloaded upon each navigation within the SPA.